# Where should I put an image so that i can use it as an og:image?

Tags: html, facebook, seo, meta-tags

I want to use an image in `<meta property="og:image" content="" />` but I have that image in my file.

I know that we cannot use relative link in this.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="img/socialImage.png" />
```

Then where should I put this image so that I can use it in meta tag. How I can use my image as URL?

Comment: content should be a URL that points to the image.

Comment: But how I can get URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your application is hosted on a domain and publicly accessible your image will become accessible via web crawlers. At this point it can be picked up inside the `og:image` meta. All you need to do is host the image publicly on your application and put the full URL in the meta tag. For example `<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/socialImage.png" />`